# Sampling from a mixture of product of Gaussians

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo

I have the following density:

$$p(y_*)=\int N(y_*\mid \mu(x_*),\Sigma(x_*) )\cdot N(x_*\mid Ax,Q)p(x,\theta)\ dx \ d\theta \ dx_*$$

with $\theta=(A,Q,\mu(\cdot),\Sigma(\cdot))$.

How can I sample from the above distribution?

Let's assume I can sample from $p(x,\theta)$.

$$p(y_*)\approx \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N}\int N(y_*\mid \mu_i(x_*),\Sigma_i(x_*) )\cdot N(x_*\mid A_i x_i,Q_i)\ dx_*$$

where the quantities indexed by $i$ come from a Monte Carlo sampling method.

Using again the same technique for approximating the distribution, we have

$$p(y_*)\approx  \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{1}{N_x}\sum_{j=1}^{N_x} N(y_*\mid \mu_i([x_*]_{ij}),\Sigma_i([x_*]_{ij}) )$$

where $[x_*]_{ij}\sim N(x_*\mid A_i x_i,Q_i)$

Is this last aproximation correct? Are there any studies on the suitability of such approximations?

To sample from the approximation, I would draw 2 vectors $v_y,u_x$ from a uniform(0,1). The $v_y$ would determine which $i$'s I would draw, and $u_x$ the $j$'s I would draw.

Comment: Use the right order of simulations to exploit the hierarchical structure of the model: (a) $(x,\theta)$; (b) $x^\star$; (c) $y^\star$.